# iOS Notification sound playing in app, although this hasn't been initiated by me (iOS 12 only)

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, pascal, rad-studio

Ever since updating devices to iOS 12, my Delphi application has started playing sound notifications when a specific operation is done in the application. This has not been coded or configured by me. When using the application in iOS 11 or lower, the sound notification does not play.

The project is built and compiled in Delphi 10.3.1. I cannot find any mentions of this phenomena anywhere in the RAD Studio documentation, or online. Disabling notifications for the application in the iOS settings does work, however this solution has its drawbacks obviously.

Edit: This is the documentation I have been reading: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_Notifications_(iOS_and_Android)

This operation, when initiated, starts an animation of a spinning wheel, indicating waiting (not TAniIndicator). A TTimer is also started at this point, indicating to the user how long the wait has been. However, I cannot see how the event handler in the timer could make this happen:

```pascal
procedure MainForm.timer_loadingTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  tt_loadingText.Tag   := tt_loadingText.Tag + 1;
  tt_loadingText.Text  := tt_loadingText.Tag.ToString + ' seconds.';
end;
```

Has anyone ever run into the same issue, and has any idea what could cause it? 
I suspect there is some configuration somewhere, or maybe it is a side effect hidden deep in my code.

Comment: Without a [mcve], it would be hard to determine

Comment: I would guess these are probably default sounds that are attached to some of the common notification types by the OS itself and not your application. So whenever your application creates one of these notification the default sound is being played by the OS. If this is indeed the case I'm pretty sure you can find apropriate personalization settings in the new iOS to change sounds for these common notification types or even disable them.

Comment: @DaveNottage yes, I understand, however I was unable to create a reproducible example without an unacceptable amount of code - this was more of a wild card to see if anybody else has experienced the same thing, since I cannot find any Delphi documentation about the phenomena.

Comment: @SilverWarior thanks, I will look for this as a patch-up solution. Still no idea why my application is creating these notifications though.

Comment: @Mint Your question says: "..playing sound notifications when a specific operation is done in the application". If it's a specific operation, are you unable to create a test project that does that operation?

Comment: @DaveNottage yes, this is correct. I am able to create a test project that performs the operation, however in the test project the notification sound doesn't play - I have tried adding and removing different aspects, but I cannot get the sound to play unless I am using the full project.